# MVC3 Razor Templates - EditorForModel

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So, I'm following [this article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) to customise the Html.EditorForModel template. Had it working - fine.

I tried converting it to Razor (Object.cshtml) and get:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
Compiler Error Message: CS0115: 'ASP._Page_Views_Shared_EditorTemplates_Object_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override

Source Error:


Line 44:         }
Line 45:         
Line 46:         public override void Execute() {
Line 47: 
Line 48:
```

Here's the code

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl
@{  var count = 0; }
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { 
  @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} 
else { 
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
    @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) {
      if(prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) 
      } 
      else { 
        if(count == 2) {
          count = 0;
          @:</tr><tr>
        } 
        else {
          count++;
        }
        <td>hi
          <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
            @prop.IsRequired ? "*" : "" 
            @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName) 
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) 
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*") 
          </div>
        </td>
      } 
    } 
    </tr>
  </table>
}
```

I'm out of guesswork.

"Interestingly" when the template is called "_Object.cshtml", `@Html.EditorForModel("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_Object.cshtml")` is completely ignored and the default template is used, so knowing why is has to be called "Object" would be a nice to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the first line (the `@inherits` stuff):

```
@{ var count = 0; }
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { 
  @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} 
else { 
  <table class="form">
    <tr>
    @foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) {
      if(prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) 
      } 
      else { 
        if(count == 2) {
          count = 0;
          @:</tr><tr>
        } 
        else {
          count++;
        }
        <td>hi
          <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
            @if (prop.IsRequired)
            {
                @:*   
            }
            @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName) 
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) 
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*") 
          </div>
        </td>
      } 
    } 
    </tr>
  </table>
}
```

Also notice the way I rewrote the `@prop.IsRequired` test.